# Should I leave the work?

Tags: work-environment, job-change, germany

I'm studying applied computer science and since last year I am working for a respected company. I was very happy when I found out that they will hire me. But things didn't go how I wanted and I am unhappy here at my company. I feel that I can't develop my skills in programming and that my skills are stuck at the same point.

I feel like my supervisor does not care about me. She gave me a task, but I told her that I have never worked with that and that I don't know how this works but she didn't care, and still gave me the task. And now I feel stressed to complete the task on time. If I I take too long on the task, it'll reflect poorly. Every time when I think of my work on Sunday, I get very uncomfortable.

The things that hold me here are that I want to start with my Masters in October and here in my current job I am working only 10 hours a week. And when I change the work I guess it will unlikely that I will work again for 10 hours a week. And when I start with my Master, I will get a good payment at my current work. Could you give me some advices what I should do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First sign that you should look for another job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/138116/first-sign-that-you-should-look-for-another-job)

Comment: What are some of the specific things that are making you feel uncomfortable now?

Comment: So, I am working the section for embedded systems. And for example for the last two or three weeks I couldn't work on my project. So I had to read some documentations. The reason was that a co-worker had work on the hardware system that I am also working on. And if I do something wrong he gets very angry. You also have to know that he is above me. I am just a hiwi and he is employed. And I am not happy with the work. I thought I would do more programming. But I do it very rare. For example: When I appeared at worked and started to work on the hardware, the co-worker came and said:

Comment: "What are you doing?, who told you that you can work on it? ..." In very unpolite way. But I was always working on it and suddenly it was a problem. And when I told my supervisor that I have problems with my project, she told me that I should ask another one there, who has more experience. When I did that, he was not a help. He just asked some questions to me, why I can't do it. But also in a way, where I felt that I am very useless there. And when I started here I wanted to write my bachelor thesis here in the company, I also talked to my supervisor and she was ok with it ->

Comment: -> She can't speak well german so she told me that if I write my thesis in german that she has to ask another co-worker if she can correct my work. My supervisor said that everything will be fine and that I can write it in english. And after a few month I asked her again if I can start with my thesis, she said to me that I have to write it in english. And there I felt betrayed, because the main reason why I started to work was that I could write my thesis in a company

Comment: If it was pleasant and fun to do you probably wouldn't get paid.    Buckle down and get to work.    It will get better in time.

Comment: I read a lot of tell-tales here that @S.Yildiz works on a student contract at a company in germany. It might be prudent to reflect that in the tags.

Answer (score 6):

I feel as though these two points are contradictory.

> But things didn't go how I wanted and I am unhappy here at my company. I feel that I can't develop my skills in programming and that my skills are stuck at the same point.

and

> I feel like my supervisor does not care about me. She gave me a task, but I told her that I have never worked with that and that I don't know how this works but she didn't care, and still gave me the task.

You state you want to develop your skills, but feel as though your supervisor doesn't care about you because you were given a task you don't know how to do. But that's precisely the situation that pushes you to learn new skills. I have rarely been given or picked up a project I knew exactly know to do right away, but that's part of the job and common in STEM professions.

Now if your manager gave you an impossible deadline and no support/direction in learning the new skills that's different. If you encounter those issues you should discuss with her.

Comment: I meant I want to improve my programming skills and in the project I am working on, I don't have to program. I have to config many things.

Comment: @S.Yildiz Was that communicated to your manager and what did she say?

Comment: I got a mail from her that she will leave the work next month. When I told her that I have still problems, she told me that she will send someone else, a hiwi, and that I will work together with someone else. But months have passed and I am still working alone on the project

Comment: @S.Yildiz I would keep following up with your manager. Unfortunately, people forget to do things all the time, but if it benefits you, you should definitely keep following up.

Answer (score 3):

Your supervisor is giving you the chance to learn. Take it! If you need guidance, ask a co-worker or use your favorite internet search engine. Supervisors know it takes time and effort to learn things. That's why your supervisor gave you this assignment.

If nobody else at your company knows how to do this particular thing, you have a great opportunity: to become the local expert on the subject.

You have chosen a field which requires you to learn something new every day. Decades from now you still will learn new things all the time.  Get used to it! Seriously.

And be patient with yourself.

Of course, if you need a full-time job, not just a 10-hour/week job, then don't hesitate to find one.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I guess I just have a lack of job experience. And because this is my first place I am working, I feel like that. I think I have to be more experienced.